# how to get distinct non-aggregated columns along with aggregated column when group by clause is applied in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select sum(col1), distinct col2 from table group by col1;
```

Above query fails. Is there an alternative to get distinct value if all the values in the group are unique?

For ex 1(if value in col2 is same):

```
|col1 | col2 |
|-----|------|
|1    |  2   |
|1    |  2   |
```

the output should be:

```
|col1(sum) |col2 |
|----------|-----|
|    2     |  2  |
```

ex 2(if value in col2 is different):

```
|col1 | col2 |
|-----|------|
|1    |  2   |
|1    |  3   |
```

the output should be:

```
|col1(sum) | col2 |
|----------|------|
|    2     |'...' |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is not an operation that is applied to a single column - it applies to all columns and does not make sense in the context of an aggregation.

> the output should be:
>
> ```
> col1(sum) col2
> 2         '...'
> ```

You can use a case statement to get your desired output but you will need to have all the outputs from the case statement having the same data-type; so, if you want `...` when there are multiple values then you will need to convert your numbers to a string:

```
SELECT SUM( col1 ),
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT( DISTINCT col2 ) = 1
       THEN TO_CHAR( MAX( col2 ) )
       ELSE '...'
       END
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `GROUP BY col1`.

Have a `case` expression that returns col2 if there is only one distinct col2 value (for that col1 group.) Othwerwise return -999 (or any other value you chose).

```
select sum(col1),
       case when count(distinct col2) = 1 then max(col2)
            else -999
       end
from t
group by col1
```